# Why can't I post to API with Glassfish server?

Tags: java, api, web-services, jax-rs, token

I am trying to do a POST to an API and I keep getting this error.

```
StandardWrapperValve[com.mycompany.timeedit.JAXRSConfiguration]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.mycompany.timeedit.JAXRSConfiguration threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel.getProperties(SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.SystemPropertiesConfigurationProvider.getProperties(SystemPropertiesConfigurationProvider.java:29)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.readExternalPropertiesMap(ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.configure(ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFeature.configure(ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFeature.java:26)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:677)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:611)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.configureMetaProviders(ClientConfig.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:802)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:84)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:421)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:327)
    at TestAPI.Http_Connection.addToCanvas(Http_Connection.java:80)
    at TestAPI.CanvasResource.getJson(CanvasResource.java:69)
    at TestAPI.CanvasResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getJson(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Below is my webservice.

This service is accepting a string from a jquery-ajax method that I have made aswell. But that one seems to work fine so I am not going to paste it here.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;



@Path("canvas")
@RequestScoped
public class CanvasResource  {




    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public CanvasResource() {
    }


    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getJson(String schema ){


        Gson g = new Gson();

        Type userListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<TimeEdit2>>(){}.getType();
        ArrayList<TimeEdit2> userArray = g.fromJson(schema, userListType); 


        Http_Connection hc = new Http_Connection();//Http_Connection is the name of my class
        try {       
            hc.addToCanvas(userArray);
        } 
        catch (ProtocolException ex) {
            System.out.println("1 !!"+ex);
            Logger.getLogger(CanvasResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("2 !! "+ex);
            Logger.getLogger(CanvasResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

       return Response
                .ok("ping")
                .build();
    }
```

This is my class that I want to post to API.

I have tried to run the class just being a main-method and that works fine, but when I make it a method and send from my webservice to my class, that's when it breaks....

The program breaks on the "Response r = invocationB...."

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.oauth2.OAuth2ClientSupport;

public class Http_Connection {

//public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException    

    public void addToCanvas(ArrayList <TimeEdit2> timeEdit) throws MalformedURLException, 
                                                               ProtocolException, IOException
{

        String canvas_url = "https://ltu.instructure.com/api/v1/calendar_events.json";
        String bearerToken = "<myToken>";
        String context_code= "<myUser>";

    URL url = new URL(canvas_url);

    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("calendar_event[context_code]", <myUser> );
    form.param("calendar_event[title]", "testing");
    form.param("calendar_event[start_at]", "2020-01-20T17:00:00Z");
    form.param("calendar_event[end_at]", "2020-01-20T20:00:00Z");
    form.param("calendar_event[description]","beskrivning");


HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(OAuth2ClientSupport.feature(bearerToken));
            WebTarget target = client.target(canvas_url);

            Invocation.Builder invocationB = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
            Response r = invocationB.post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));
```

This is my pom.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>TimeEdit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>TimeEdit-1.0-SNAPSHOT</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My IDE is Apache Netbeans IDE 11.2

At the moment, Im using Glassfish 5.1 with Java EE 8 and JDK 1.8.

I have tried other version of glassfish, Java EE and JDK but nothing is working... Have had this error for a couple of weeks now...

This is my second try using Webservices and the first time that Im sending to API, so I really need help

Comment: Glassfish already comes with Jersey included in its internal library. In your pom.xml you are including Jersey also. So it's possible to have conflicting versions. If you want to use the new version of Jersey, you can try to [update version of Jersey in Glassfish](https://blog.dejavu.sk/updating-jersey-2-in-glassfish-4/). What you also want to do is make sure your dependencies in your pom use the `<scope>provided</scope>` so they are not included in the build and you just use the version that's already included in Glassfish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @PaulSamsotha ! I tried the provided scope, but that just gave me ClassNotFound exception. It works for my friends, but they are using Mac-computers, I use a PC and Windows 10. Is that affecting anything?